# Emacs GNUS nnrss issue

Tags: emacs, gnus

I started to use nnrss as rss reader. Got couple feeds including slashdot. 
What is strange: some feeds are fetched fine, but slashdot feeds are seems to be duplicated each time I fetch them. Just like as nnrss do not track that some of posts it fetches are actually old posts I have already read (and they are marked read). 
Some other feeds are tracked fine.
What should I check and try to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I read the Slashdot RSS feed through Google Reader and see similar repeats of stories. I believe it happens because the stories get (re)published to the RSS feed any time an edit of the story details happens. At least, that's what I've always assumed. Some other feeds for other sites behave similarly with repeated items.